# Viewing javascript source maps visually

Tags: source-maps

I remember finding a source map viewer somewhere one time, which showed you the source and the source-map side by side (i think also with the compiled code), and let you scroll your mouse around to see different parts of the source map.

I can't for the life of me find it now, but I really want to use it to verify the integrity of my source map (can't tell if bug in the map or in chrome).

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Also asked on [softwarerecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17476).

Answer (score 16):

Oh, YES I found it! From the guy who gave us webpack:

http://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/

Answer (score 3):

http://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/ didn't work for me out of box because my project was too big.

I strongly recommend https://github.com/evanw/source-map-visualization as an alternative, also because I like how compact it is. Just open index.html, drag & drop files and it worked like charm.